# Job Scheduling with Apache Quartz + Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, quartz-scheduler

I am new to Apache-Quartz and I want to use in my spring-boot project. I just want to ask a few questions. I have read the documentation and I want to use quartz with postgreSQL. However, my first question:

1-) JobDataMap is used for keep some data in JobDetails so in PostgreSQL, documentation says: Only store primitive data types JobDataMap to avoid data serialization issues short and long-term.

Can I store my custom objects in it ? Can it be stored as a different tables if I want to schedule more than one Job classes like Job1.class, Job2.class, Job3.class etc.? If it is same table in postgreSQL the jobDataMap column will be different, right ? Or does it depend to Scheduler to Scheduler I mean each Scheduler will be stored as different table ?

2-) I can not exactly understand that which way I should implement. I want to code my own quartz library so my microservices should import my library and use common methods to inject quartz and related classes which implement Job interface. This way should I use Spring quartz or just the quartz ? It looks to me very complicated because examples are not quite readable. May be I am thinking wrongly :/

Am I able to do that use only Quartz library with using PostgreSQL properties using

org.quartz.jobStore.class=org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX
org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass=org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.PostgreSQLDelegate

and only and only importing quartz dependency

```
        <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
        <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.3</version>
```

Job etc etc ? Can I create dynamic trigger,job & job details when I connect with the REST API, so users can able to create a job from outside ? With this way, do I need to configure trigger,job as a bean ? Can I submit them to  my Scheduler with created dynamically Triggers & Job Details ?

Or should I import spring-context-support to  my pom.xml to be able to use PersistableCronTriggerFactoryBean, SimpleTriggerFactoryBean, JobDetailFactoryBean beans and configure them dynamically by writing static methods in some Util class.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Can anyone give an idea about my questions & share your experience please ? :)

Thanks !